# Nested extern declaration warning freebsd kernel

Tags: freebsd, kernel-module, kernel

I am modifying [sched_ule.c](http://www.leidinger.net/FreeBSD/dox/kern/html/dd/d9d/sched__ule_8c_source.html) in freebsd kernel. To print the debugging messages i am using the [syslog](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/syslog/) function. But during compilation we are getting the following error:

```
/usr/src/sys/kern/sched_ule.c:731: warning: implicit declaration of 
function 'syslog' /usr/src/sys/kern/sched_ule.c:731: warning: nested

extern declaration of 'syslog' [-Wnested-externs]
*** Error code 1 Stop in /usr/obj/usr/src/sys/MYKERNEL.
*** Error code 1 Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1 Stop in /usr/src.
```

I have also included the following headers:
**syslog.h, stdarg.h** and have also tried compiling without them.

Comment: Show us that 731 line.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call libc functions (which run in user space) from the kernel.

Use [printf(9)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/9/printf/) or [log(9)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/9/printf/) instead.